# Custom Android Keyboard accessing camera and microphone?

Tags: java, android, camera, microphone

I originally wanted to make a keyboard in IOS that accesses the camera and microphone but found IOS will not let you access these directly with 3rd party keyboard and background processes. I've looked everywhere to see if this is the same with Android but can not find any information. Does anyone have an experience with this? Is it possible? Or think of any ways around this with either platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible on Android. Android has API support for third part developers to access camera and microphone.  [Camera api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)